# Specification of SOAP wsdl for UsernameToken

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm writing a client to connect to a SOAP webservice using a WSDL first approach. For implementation I am using Apache CXF version 3.1.4

When testing I get the following exception:

`12:35:15.492 [main] WARN  o.a.c.w.p.a.w.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider - Failed to build the policy 'UsernameToken':sp:UsernameToken must have an inner wsp:Policy element
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: sp:UsernameToken must have an inner wsp:Policy element
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getPing(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sp:UsernameToken must have an inner wsp:Policy element
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.UsernameTokenBuilder.build(UsernameTokenBuilder.java:52)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.UsernameTokenBuilder.build(UsernameTokenBuilder.java:34)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)`

The relevant part of the WSDL file looks like this:

`<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SupportingTokens>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SupportingTokens>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>`

The error message indicates that CXF expects a policy tag under UsernameToken. And indeed, while researching I came across a [comment from CXF bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5132?focusedCommentId=13709887&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13709887):

*`Yes... Per spec, the <sp:UsernameToken> element MUST contain an internal wsp:Policy element. It should look like:
<sp:UsernameToken
    sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:WssUsernameToken11 />
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:UsernameToken>`*

But, [the specification says](http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/ws-securitypolicy.pdf):

`/sp:UsernameToken/wsp:Policy
This optional element identifies additional requirements for use of the
sp:UsernameToken assertion.`

Note: Optional.

So which one is it? It seems that CXf requires a policy while the specification says it is optional. Is there another specification I need to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the question was fairly unnoticed here on SO, but in google leads someone here, I might as well post the solution.

I posted the same question on the [Apache CXF user mailing list](https://cxf.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) and got a reply:

*It's a bug in WSS4J which I've just fixed: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-564*

*WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2 + 1.3 require a policy Element, but 1.1 doesn't. 
Until the next WSS4J release, your best bet is just to have an empty policy 
Element.*

Comment: You just saved me a few minutes/hours/days of research, thanks!